# How to read all files that ends with .csv only from Datalake on Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I want to read files (on datalake) that ends with .csv into databricks. The file names doesn't have a defined format but the underlying data in all csvs have same schema.

I want to be able to read all the csvs at one go.

[Please see the attached image for more details in the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqueT.png)

Comment: Wouldn't pattern matching work? https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/scala/pattern-match-files-in-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply patter matching while reading the files.

You should read the files like this:

```
spark.read.format("csv").load("/mnt/some-mount-point/*.csv")
```

Materials:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/scala/pattern-match-files-in-path